# add multiple params in http.HandlerFunc

Tags: go

hi i am trying tr write unit test for a post request using

```
"net/http"
"net/http/httptest"
```

if in my handler i have extra parameter other than w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request like db , kafka, etc

```
func ResponseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *dynamo.DB, p *Confluent.Producer)
```

how can i do

```
handler := http.HandlerFunc(handlername) any idea ?
```

I m getting
***cannot convert ResponseHandler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, *dynamo.DB, *"github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka".Producer)) to type http.HandlerFunc***

Answer (score 4):

Your handler needs to implement the `http.Handler` signature, meaning it cannot have other arguments or return anything.

The way to provide it with other arguments is to have them come from an outer scope. So, assuming your not-really-a-`Handler` looks like:

```golang
func ResponseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *dynamo.DB, p *Confluent.Producer)
```

...you will need to generate an actual `Handler` calling your not-really-a-`Handler`. Supposing you already obtained the DB and Producer in your router initialization function, you can route like this:

```golang
var db *dynamo.DB = someDBFactory()
var p *Confluent.Producer = giveMeAProducer()

responseHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return ResponseHandler(w, r, db, p)
})

http.HandleFunc(somePath, responseHandler)
```

You could also pass the parameters explicitly instead of relying on the outer scope, using a higher-order function:

```golang
var db *dynamo.DB := someDBFactory()
var p *Confluent.Producer := giveMeAProducer()

newResponseHandler := func(db *dynamo.DB, p *Confluent.Producer) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        return ResponseHandler(w, r, db, p)
    })
})

http.HandleFunc(somePath, newResponseHandler(db, p))
```

Comment: Global state is best avoided. Why not declare the handler as a method and get `db` and `p` from its receiver instead?

Comment: @jub0bs They can be local variables for a closure or fields on a struct for a method for this approach to work.  In this answer I think `db` and `p` are intended to be local variables, and the `var` is just to try to show their types... but it's using `var` and `:=` which will not compile, so it's probably just a mistake.

Comment: @KyleLemons fixed the typo. I did indeed have := originally and switched to var in the editor to show types, but forgot to remove the ":".

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the HandlerFunc with your custom function as

```
func ResponseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *dynamo.DB, p *Confluent.Producer)func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){
return func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){
    // your code goes here
}}
```

Comment: I don't think you can acquire `w htt.Writer` or `r *http.Request` when you call `http.Handle`, where `http.HandlerFunc` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I may wrong, but the two "extra" parameters (`db *dynamo.DB` and `p *Confluent.Producer`) don't seem request-specific. If the handler depends on them to handle requests, you could make those dependencies available to the handler in several ways. [Seasoned Gophers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DVV36uqQ4E&t=19m40s) tend to "inject" dependencies through a method receiver.

You could declare a custom struct type whose fields are the dependencies needed by your handler(s):

```
type API struct {
    db *dynamo.DB
    p  *Confluent.Producer
}
```

You can drop the extra two parameters and turn your `ResponseHandler` function into a method on your custom `API` type, thereby making it compatible with the `http.HandlerFunc` type:

```
func (api *API) ResponseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ...
}
```

Finally, you only have to wire the dependencies in an `API` variable in `main`.